# Vitejs is loading the whole bundle size instead of the selected ones

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am using vue 3 with vite. I noticed something strage. Oh vue icons is loading something like 108 MB of bundle size and it takes a lot of time to load even in vitejs.
Here's my setup

```
import { addIcons, OhVueIcon } from 'oh-vue-icons'
import {
  FaFacebookSquare,
  FaInstagram,
  FaLinkedin,
  FaQuora,
  FaTwitter,
  FaYoutube,
} from 'oh-vue-icons/icons'

// register the icons
addIcons(
  FaFacebookSquare,
  FaInstagram,
  FaLinkedin,
  FaQuora,
  FaTwitter,
  FaYoutube
)

const app = createApp(App)
app.component('VIcon', OhVueIcon)
app.mount('#app')
```

Then in my component:

```html
<VIcon name="fa-facebook-square" />
<VIcon name="fa-youtube" />
<VIcon name="fa-instagram" />
<VIcon name="fa-quora" />
<VIcon name="fa-linkedin" />
<VIcon name="fa-twitter" />
```

You can see the problem below. I am conditionally controlling these six icons. That's why there are only one or two icons per card.

[image: temp]

Why is it loading 108 MB of javascript? That doesn't make any sense. Also I am using vite with vue3. Do I need to add any extra configuration?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#the-why):

> **Performance:** Vite converts ESM dependencies with many internal modules into a single module to improve subsequent page load performance.
>
> Some packages ship their ES modules builds as many separate files importing one another. For example, [`lodash-es` has over 600 internal modules](https://unpkg.com/browse/lodash-es/)! When we do `import { debounce } from 'lodash-es'`, the browser fires off 600+ HTTP requests at the same time! Even though the server has no problem handling them, the large amount of requests create a network congestion on the browser side, causing the page to load noticeably slower.
>
> By pre-bundling `lodash-es` into a single module, we now only need one HTTP request instead!

`oh-vue-icons/icons` [contains *many* files](https://unpkg.com/browse/oh-vue-icons@1.0.0-rc2/icons/) that Vite is pre-bundling at startup.

Since you don't really need the icons to be prebundled, you can opt out of the prebundling with [`optimizeDeps.exclude`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#optimizedeps-exclude):

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  ⋮
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['oh-vue-icons/icons']
  }
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-exclude-oh-vue-icons-icons-from-prebundle?file=vite.config.js)